# How to compute KL-divergence for a product distribution using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability, probability-distribution

I want to compute the KL divergence  **D*KL*( ∏q(zk|x) ‖ p(z) )** in tensorflow

---

where **∏q(zk|x) is the product of N distributions** (k=1 to k=N), not independent, each of type tensorflow_probability.layers.MultivariateNormalTriL. p(z) is a tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag.
The KL divergence between a single q(z|x) and p(z) : D*KL*(q(z|x) ‖ p(z)) works.

---

I've tried to **subclass** the tfp Distributions class to create a product distribution Q(z) = ∏q(zk|x)
and then compute D*KL*(Q(z) ‖ p(z)) but i had to implement the _kl_divergence function, it took me back to start.

---

I would like to solve this with tensorflow-probability or at least tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an analytic KL for this case. But since KL[q||p] is q(x)*log_q(x)-q(x)*log_p(x) you could use a monte carlo approximation for KL. In TFP this probably looks like:

```py
q = QDist(...)
p = MVNDiag(...)
x = q.sample()  # x ~ q(x)
kl = q.log_prob(x) - p.log_prob(x)
```

or, for lower variance

```py
x = q.sample(10)  # x ~ q(x)
kl = tf.math.reduce_mean(q.log_prob(x) - p.log_prob(x))
```